# fortran dummy argument doesn't match actual argument. casting available?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I've recently inherited Fortran code that used to be built with an older version of the Intel Visual Fortran compiler.  There's a section of code that used to compile, but now throws an error #6633 'The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.'

The problem is when a function called `READ_AND_CONVERT` is called with `REAL*4` `DATA_ARRAY(*)`, but in `READ_AND_CONVERT` that parameter is declared as `INT*2`. I think it really just wants the address of the `DATA_ARRAY`.

Is there a way to pass the address of the `DATA_ARRAY`, even though they're of different types?

Here is `READ_AND_CONVERT`:

```
      SUBROUTINE READ_AND_CONVERT (MX, N)
C=======================================================================
C     Reads Integer*2 Data Array and Converts it to Real*4.
C
C     This is a service routine called by subroutines
C     READ_XYZ_2, READ_XYZ_4, READ_XYZ_ALL and READ_XYZ_FULL
C=======================================================================
C
      IMPLICIT  NONE
C
      INCLUDE   'XYZ.FOR'
      INCLUDE   'COMMON_XYZIO.FOR'
      INCLUDE   'COMMON_HDR.FOR'
C
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C     Local Parameters
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C
      LOGICAL    BB_FOUND
      INTEGER*2  MX, MY
      INTEGER*4  N, J
      REAL*4     YJ, BB
C
      DIMENSION MX(*), MY(2)
      EQUIVALENCE (YJ, MY(1))
C
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C
      CALL GET_REAL_PARAMETER ('XYZ$_OFFSET', BB, BB_FOUND)
C
      READ (LUGIN) (MX(J), J = 1,N)
C
      IF (BB_FOUND) THEN
         DO J = N, 1, -1
            YJ        = (SCALE_FACTOR * MX(J)) + BB
            MX(2*J)   = MY(2)
            MX(2*J-1) = MY(1)
         END DO
      ELSE
         DO J = N, 1, -1
            YJ        = SCALE_FACTOR * MX(J)
            MX(2*J)   = MY(2)
            MX(2*J-1) = MY(1)
         END DO
      END IF
C
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: You really need to tag your question better to receive some attention. I did not catch it even when I subscribe to [fortran*]. There are only 41 followers of [tag:intel-fortran] and 1500 followers of [tag:fortran].

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/289586): 
Basically disable the warning...  by setting Properties | Fortran | Diagnostics | Check Routine Interfaces [change from Yes to No]

The article also shows how to do casting, in their example of a complex array to a real array:

```
use ISO_C_BINDING

complex(8), allocatable :: c(:)
real(8), pointer:: p(:)

allocate(c(N))
call C_F_POINTER(C_LOC(c), p, [2*N])
call donothing(N, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are directives in Intel Fortran which disable the argument type check for a given routine and for a given argument. To disable the checks for all your code is dangerous!

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK :: ARGUMENT_NAME
```

source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/288896